# How get have WGET search for a file within all subdirectories without listing each subdirectory?

Tags: bash, wget

There are some file that I want to download using WGET in a bash script. Each image is in one of many available subdirectories. I'm able to use WGET to sift through each subdirectory by listing them out by name. However, there are so many subdirectories that I'd like to find a way to ask WGET to search all subdirectories without listing them out (20150125_028445 20150125_028450 20150126_028454 are examples, but there are more). How do I do this? Here is my current code:

```sh
declare -a image=("lor_0299176871_0x636_sci.fit" "lor_0299176907_0x636_sci.fit" "lor_0299176943_0x636_sci.fit") 

address='https://pds-smallbodies.astro.umd.edu/holdings/nh-p-lorri-3-pluto-v2.0/data/' 

possibilities=( 20150125_028445 20150125_028450 20150126_028454 )  

for file in "${image[@]}" 
do
  for possibility in "${possibilities[@]}"
  do
    wget "$address$possibility/$file" && break
  done
done
```

Comment: Are there links of the subdirectories?  If so, you can use the -r (--recursive) flag with wget, and it will traverse this for you.  You can then use -l (depth) flag if you want to ensure you don't traverse the link directory too far.

Comment: There is an [index file](https://pds-smallbodies.astro.umd.edu/holdings/nh-p-lorri-3-pluto-v2.0/index/index.tab) that can be used to convert file names to their full URLs.